Moving samples between classes in eCognition 9.01
I’m currently using eCognition 9.01 and have encountered an issue with transferring samples between classes. Here’s the situation:
I collected samples for a class called Ck and wanted to duplicate those samples and move them to a new class called 22.
After duplicating and assigning the samples to class 22, I noticed that only the class label was moved, but the samples themselves did not carry over. When I try to use these duplicated samples, I get a "domain is empty" error.
It seems that since the samples were not originally created under class 22, the domain for the samples in this class is not recognized, making it impossible to use them in classification. Since there are so many classes that I want to classify like class 22, I want to use only Ck samples while classifying these classes.
The issue is slowing down my workflow significantly, as I was hoping to reuse the samples collected for class Ck to define class 22 more efficiently. Does anyone know how I can successfully transfer samples to a new class while ensuring they remain functional and usable?
